# HelpScout Mailbox API 2.0 400 bad request while migrating conversation threads

Tags: php, api

**PHP version:** 7.2

**SDK version:** v2

**Error details:**

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Client error: `POST https://api.helpscout.net/v2/conversations` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"logRef":"eab45a81-90a1-4f40-8a61-7b7dc0c43981#289130283","message":"Error parsing request body into JSON","_embedded": (truncated...)

in /home/avee/sites/wte/wp-content/plugins/helpscout-migrate/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113

I am using HelpScout Mailbox API 2.0 to migrate my mailbox from one account to another.

https://github.com/helpscout/helpscout-api-php

I am trying to migrate the conversation threads however getting bad request error while creating a new conversation. I am trying to use getThreads() to get conversation threads and setThreads() to add threads data to a new conversation.

Here's my code:

````
$conversationRequest = (new ConversationRequest())
->withThreads();
$conversationRequest = $conversationRequest->withThreads();

$filters = (new ConversationFilters())
    ->withMailbox($from_mailboxid)
    ->withSortField('createdAt')
    ->withSortOrder('asc')
    ->withStatus('all');

// $second_page = $from_conversations->getPage(2);
$from_conversations = $from_client->conversations()->list($filters, $conversationRequest);

foreach( $from_conversations as $key => $conv ) {
    /**
     * Create Conversation: Customer thread - as if the customer emailed in
     */
    $customer = $conv->getCustomer();
    $thread   = $conv->getThreads();
    $subject  = $conv->getSubject();
    $status   = $conv->getStatus();
    $type     = $conv->getType();

    $conversation = new Conversation();
    $conversation->setSubject( $subject );
    $conversation->setStatus( $status );
    $conversation->setType( $type );
    $conversation->setMailboxId( $to_mailboxid );
    $conversation->setCustomer( $customer );
    $conversation->setThreads( $thread );

    try {
        $conversationId = $to_client->conversations()->create($conversation);
    } catch (\HelpScout\Api\Exception\ValidationErrorException $e) {
        var_dump($e->getError()->getErrors());
    }```
````

Comment: Can you add the specific error text to the question as it may help understand the issue.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post.